# Grails render() with a fragment parameter

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Is there a way to use render() with a fragment param so on page load it automatically scrolls to a specific part of the page? Similarly to how we can call

```
redirect(controller: "book", action: "show", fragment: "profile")
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass it to [`render()`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html), because by the time you're actually invoking `render()`, the URL has **already been determined** and mapped to your action; all render is doing is controlling what gets written back to the response.

The fragment **must already be in the URL** before the rendering controller action gets called. Here's an example:

*`grails-app/controllers/MyController.groovy`*

```
class MyController {
    def foo = {
        render(view: 'foo')
    }

    def quux = {
        redirect(action: 'foo', fragment: 'baz')
    }
}
```

*`grails-app/views/my/foo.gsp`*

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Foo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a id="bar">Bar</a>
    <g:each in="${0..100}"><br/></g:each>
    <a id="baz">Baz</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

With various URLs:

```
http://example.com/myapp/my/foo     - doesn't scroll to an anchor
http://example.com/myapp/my/foo#baz - scrolls to the 'baz' anchor
http://example.com/myapp/my/quux    - scrolls to the 'baz' anchor'
```

Comment: The reason I'm not using redirect() right now is the fact that I need to keep the model. Is there a common workaround for that? The first thing that comes to mind is something like this:
`code`
class MyController {
    def model = [:]
    def foo = {
        render(view: 'foo', model: model)
    }

    def quux = {
        model.message = 'hey you'
        redirect(action: 'foo', fragment: 'baz')
    }
}`code`

Comment: @Slavko - I think I see what you're trying to do; I'll have to think about it for a while. An option is to use the session to preserve the model, but that's not very elegant.

Comment: why does the third example scroll to `baz` anchor?

Comment: @spartacus - Because the `quux` action in the controller redirects to `/foo#baz`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to specify a fragment directly with a grails render call, but in my code I'm using a work around that seems to provide most of the desired functionality with only a little extra complexity.  The trick is to pass in the desired fragment reference as a part of the model, and then to act upon that reference in the GSP page.  Thus, the render call in my controller looks like this:

```
def foo() {
    render(view : 'foo', model:[fragment:'myFragment'])
}
```

then, down in the GSP, I access the model with the following Javascript:

```
<g:javascript>
    if ("${fragment}") {
        window.location.href = "#${fragment}";
    }
</g:javascript>
```

The GSP will then tell your browser to jump forward to the desired anchor in the page (if any).