# Grails GSP page fragment linking problems with jQuery Mobile

Tags: grails, jquery-mobile, gsp

I'm creating a single gsp for a multi-page jQuery Mobile page. There are three different fragments defined in a div like this:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
```

I've tried several ways to link to another fragment on the page without success. In all cases, the links take me back to the index page.

```
<li><g:link data-icon="arrow-r" controller="foursome" action="summary" id="${foursomeInstance.id}" fragment="page2">Page2</g:link></li>
<li><a data-icon="arrow-r" href="#back9">Page2</a></li>
<li><a data-icon="arrow-r" href="/foursome/summary/${foursomeInstance.id}#back9">Page2</a></li>
```

Is there any good material on this subject? This was helpful - [Grails render() with a fragment parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861738/graails-render-with-a-fragment-parameter)

Comment: have you checked the resulting html code? i guess its an issue with jquery-mobile: there is configuration, what links are "back" links and what are real links. also note that there is a `createLinkTo` function. if you have issues, that grails is manipulating your targets, use this function, which will only render a path. http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLinkTo.html

Comment: sorry i meant `createLink` ;-)

Comment: createLink gives me the same result. The link sometimes works which makes me think it has something to do with the path that I used to get to this page. Inspecting the HTML shows the link I expected - href="/TourneyCard/foursome/summary/1#back9". However, when I click on the link it take me to "http://localhost:8080/TourneyCard/#back9"

Comment: Thanks, @crudolf. If I go directly to the summary page by typing the URL, http://localhost:8080/TourneyCard/foursome/summary/1#page1, then the links on the summary page1 work. The normal way a user would get to this page is after a submit is done on another page and the controller action handling the submit does a redirect to summary page1. When the redirect happens the URL shown in the browser for the summary page is http://localhost:8080/TourneyCard/foursome/summary/1#/TourneyCard/foursome/postHole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is jquery-mobile issue: You need to add `rel="external"` for internal links to other pages. See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/pages/docs-pages.html